# Stuck on this error: Primary constructor body is not allowed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I watched some tutorials on Youtube for a scribt I want to have in my Unity project.
In minute 28:13  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b87iVclVT2E you can see the important part of the scribt and here is my copy of it:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    public CharacterController2D controller;
    public Animator animator;

    public float runSpeed = 40f;

    float horizontalMove = 0f;
    bool jump = false;
    bool crouch = false;

    void Update(){
        horizontalMove = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") * runSpeed;

        animator.SetFloat ("Speed", Mathf.Abs (horizontalMove));

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            jump = true;
            animator.SetBool("IsJumping", true);
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Crouch"))
        {
            crouch = true;
        } else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Crouch"))
        {
            crouch = false;
        }
    }

    public void OnLanding ()
    {
        animator.SetBool ("IsJumping", false);
    }

    public void OnCrouching (bool isCrouching);
    {
        animator.SetBool("IsCrouching", isCrouching);
    }

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        controller.Move (horizontalMove * Time.fixedDeltaTime, crouch, jump);
        jump = false;
    }
}
```

When I tryed it Unity responded with these errors:

```
    Assets/PlayerMovement.cs(42,2): error CS9010: Primary constructor body is not allowed
    Assets/PlayerMovement.cs(47,2): error CS9010: Primary constructor body is not allowed
    Assets/PlayerMovement.cs(47,2): error CS8041: Primary constructor body is not allowed
```

I would be nice if you could help :D
LG Nick

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I edited the title of your post. It's always a good idea to make the title of your posts match the problem you are trying to solve.  Two reasons. 1) So people scrolling down the list of questions can know what your problem is. 2) So search engines can catalog your problem which will help future devs facing the same error.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is a semicolon that should not be there, on this line of code:

```
public void OnCrouching (bool isCrouching); //there should not be a semicolon here
{
    animator.SetBool("IsCrouching", isCrouching);
}
```

Change to

```
public void OnCrouching (bool isCrouching)
{
    animator.SetBool("IsCrouching", isCrouching);
}
```